# Android: Save CSV File to internal Storage

Tags: java, android, csv, file

I have put somehow together a code that records my sensor data from the phone and i want to save them as csv file in some directory (maybe DCIM) in the internal Storage on the phone, but i cannot find something similar, i am also new to Android Studio and java.

On the bottom you can see ,i found that code example with
"getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath()" , how can i change that , that my file is saved on the phone in internal storage and tell him exactly where so i can find it later and use it further ?

```
package com.example.shakedemo;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView txt_currentAccel, txt_prevAccel, txt_acceleration, txt_temp;
    ProgressBar prog_shakeMeter;
    Switch switch1;

    //define Sensor Variables
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mAccelerometer;

    private SensorManager mSensorManagerNew;
    private Sensor mTemp;

    private double accelerationCurrentValue;
    private double accelerationPreviousValue;


    private int SwitchFlag = 0;

    final String TAG = "SensorLog";
    FileWriter writer;


    private SensorEventListener sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override

        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
            if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER && SwitchFlag == 1) {
                float x = sensorEvent.values[0];
                float y = sensorEvent.values[1];
                float z = sensorEvent.values[2];

                accelerationCurrentValue = Math.sqrt((x * x + y * y + z * z));
                double changeInAcceleration = Math.abs(accelerationCurrentValue - accelerationPreviousValue);

                accelerationPreviousValue = accelerationCurrentValue;

                //update text views
                txt_currentAccel.setText("Current =" + accelerationCurrentValue);
                txt_prevAccel.setText(("Prev = " + accelerationPreviousValue));
                txt_acceleration.setText("Acceleration change =" + changeInAcceleration);
                prog_shakeMeter.setProgress((int) changeInAcceleration);


                try {
                    writer.write(String.format("ACC; %f; %f; %f; %f; %f; %f\n", sensorEvent.values[0], sensorEvent.values[1], sensorEvent.values[2], 0.f, 0.f, 0.f));
                }catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

        }
    };
    private SensorEventListener sensorEventListenerNew = new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
            float temp = sensorEvent.values[0];
            txt_temp.setText("Temp = " + temp);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txt_acceleration = findViewById(R.id.txt_accel);
        txt_prevAccel = findViewById(R.id.txt_prevAccel);
        txt_currentAccel = findViewById(R.id.txt_currentAccel);
        txt_temp = findViewById(R.id.txt_temp);

        prog_shakeMeter = findViewById(R.id.prog_shakeMeter);

        switch1 = findViewById(R.id.switch1);

        // Initialize Sensors
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

        mSensorManagerNew = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mTemp = mSensorManagerNew.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);


        switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override

            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if (b == true) {

                    Log.d(TAG, "Writing to " + getStorageDir());
                    try {
                        writer = new FileWriter(new File(getStorageDir(), "sensors_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".csv"));
                    } catch (
                            IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    SwitchFlag = 1;

                } else {
                    try {
                        writer.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    SwitchFlag = 0;
                }

            }
        });


    }


    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListenerNew, mTemp, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(sensorEventListener);
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(sensorEventListenerNew);


    }


    private String getStorageDir() {
        return this.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).getAbsolutePath() instead. Dont try to save a .csv to DCIM as it will not be accepted on Android 11+ devices.

Comment: And what you consider to be internal storage is called external storage. Funny isnt it?